# Image from origin 'file://' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy:

Tags: javascript, html, cors, leaflet

I'm using leaflet-image.js to create an image from a leaflet map. The code used to create the image is the one in the example at https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image ie

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'YOUR.MAPID').setView([38.9, -77.03], 14);
leafletImage(map, function(err, canvas) {
    // now you have canvas
    // example thing to do with that canvas:
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    var dimensions = map.getSize();
    img.width = dimensions.x;
    img.height = dimensions.y;
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById('images').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('images').appendChild(img);
});
```

The problem is that the image seems to be blocked by some CORS security feature. Below is an image of the Google Chrome console (not that enevn in firefox it does not work)

[image]

Could you help me with that ?  (Also all my server are locally hosted. Webserver, mapserver ...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, javascript code running in a website cannot access resources from other websites. But a javascript from a website should be able to access resources from that same website. This is called [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), and is implemented by all major browsers (not just Chrome).

Do read also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs and [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome) .

The quickest solution is to have the image reachable via your `localhost:8080` website - then, the javascript in that website will be able to access a image resource in the same website.

Comment: Thank You. I understand it now

Answer (score 1):

You need to upload the files to a web server, if you want Chrome to allow these requests (which doesn't actually happen). This is a security measurement made by Google, so websites can't read your private files.

Comment: Sorry for asking but WHat files ? My HTML/CSS/JS files ? The image created by leaflet-image.js ?

Comment: I tried using Google Chrome Web server https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en  BUT I still get the same error `Image from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8887' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: You need to use a web server. Any server that has either Apache or Nginx (or whatever) installed on a dedicated server. You cannot bypass this on your local machine, because Google Chrome thinks it's a threat (which it could be).

Answer (score 1):

You need to send header
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
and maybe few more. 
This is security feature, without it, for example, all (js) social plugins will be extremely unsafe.

Comment: how do I do that with javascript ?  I did is with php a while ago with `<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>` from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource